# how to search for an occurrence of string in shell ignoring spaces

Tags: shell, unix

I have below parameter that needs to be checked if it is available in a file.

```
PARAMS='SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT>=45'
```

how can i check for the occurrence of the above listed parameter in a file such that the count  is 1 if it is available in the file.Also to note that it is ok to have spaces before and after the '>='.

i have the below code :

```
PARAM_COUNT=`cat file_name | tr -d "[:blank:]"  |awk '$1 ~ /^[^;#]/' | grep -i ${PARAM} | wc -l`
```

Please suggest what modification is necessary.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The awk is not needed because grep will do the reg exp
- The `wc -l` is not needed because grep can count too

```
cat input | tr -d '[:blank:]' | grep -c "^PARAMS='SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT>=45'"
```

Please note the `^` to indicate that the text should be found at the start of the line.

Or:

```
grep -c "^[[:blank:]]*PARAMS='SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT[[:blank:]]*>=[[:blank:]]*
45'" input
```

Comment: we are going to pass only the value of PARAMS ,so cannot use as suggested above as we have lot of parameters in the list of PARAMS to check.

Comment: You can change this by doing something like: `echo "PARAMS='SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT>=45'" | sed 's/\(>=\)/[[:blank:]]*\1[[:blank:]]*/g'`